# Redirect to specific page after login if not currently logged in to application

Tags: yii2

A site user clicks on an email link "/team/overview".  If the user is already logged in to the application, they see the page without any further work.  If the user is not currently logged in they are shown the login page and then, after successful authentication, they are automatically redirected to the page "team/overview".

I'm not even sure where to start with this redirect? Somewhere in the SiteController login action?

Comment: Maybe this can help you [https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user)

Comment: for a start you should look into the user component which provide `afterLogin` and `beforeLogin` events.